# How to add :format options to a named route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, format, named-routing

I've got a named route called profile and I would like to be able to access it as json. But when I look at my rake routes output I see that the (.:format) is missing. How do I add it to a named route?

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
profile     /:username              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `.format` in your path specification, like this:

```
map.profile '/:profile.:format', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

Then you'll end up with:

```
profile    /:profile(.:format)     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

Comment: I tried map.profile '/:profile(.:format)', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show' and was so surprised it didn't work. I think it should! :-)